# how to auto start service after load all views in MainActivity?

Tags: android, service, android-service

I have a problem like the above question. I want to know when all views will load on MainActivity and after loading I will start running Service. Is there any way? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can start the service in onResume() of your MainActivity. Based on the documentation:

> This is where the lifecycle components can enable any functionality
>   that needs to run while the component is visible and in the
>   foreground, such as starting a camera preview.

If lifecycle of your service is tied to that of Activity, then remember to call `stopService()` in `onPause()`. Otherwise, you have to do some condition checking beforestating the Service to avoid calling startService multiple times.